# How can I set the position of an element in React strict mode to Static? Reserved word in strict mode

Tags: reactjs, position, jsx

```
style={{position:static}
```

I want to set the element to the position static but am getting
"SyntaxError: static is a reserved word in strict mode" in the browser

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use string like this

```
style={{position:"static"}}
```

Also `static` is the default value of `position` property. You don't need to pass it unless you are changing element `position` from other value (`absolute`, `fixed` etc).